# Prop is not updating as expected when value is set in a reducer

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I encountered this problem when I was testing my newly created action and reducer. The prop is not being updated even though I'm setting it to a fixed value within my reducer.

Component:

```
class <ComponentName> extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        login()
    }
    
    render() {
        if(this.props.isLogged) 
            return (
                <App/>    
            );
        else 
            return (
                <ErrorScreen/>
            );
    }    
}



function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      isLogged:state.auth.isLogged
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        login: () => dispatch(login())
    };
};

  
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(<ComponentName>)
```

Action:

```
export function login() {
    return {
        type:"TEST"
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
const initState = {
    isLogged: false,
    
}

export default (state=initState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "TEST":
            return {
                ...state,
                isLogged: true
            }
            break;
    default:
        return state     
    }
}
```

Combine Reducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import AuthenticationReducer from './authenticationReducer'

export default combineReducers({
    auth: AuthenticationReducer
})
```

Provider:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import <ComponentName> from './app/screens/<ComponentName>'
import store from './app/store'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

export default () =>
<Provider store={store}>
  <<ComponentName>/>
</Provider>;
```

Been trying to debug this for some time now. I still don't know why this is happening. Maybe I implemented it wrongly? If there are some files I forgot to include, please inform me. Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: As a side note - `class <ComponentName> extends Component` looks like incorrect syntax. Try dropping the `<` and `>`

Comment: are you using `combineReducers()` ? if so, can you show that code? have you put break points throughout your code? does the switch case in your reducer hit as expected?

Comment: @DacreDenny Hi! Sorry for the misunderstanding, that is only a placeholder value for this question. It's not the name of the actual class :D

Comment: also, have you wrapped your app root component with a `<Provider />` ?

Comment: @DacreDenny Oh thank you for reminding me. I will update the question right away. Thanks!

Comment: @DacreDenny Yes, I wrapped my app root component with a provider. I can assure this because my other actions and reducers are working except this. I updated the question already. Sorry about that.

Comment: What happens if you add `debugger;` after `case "TEST":` - does the break point hit in dev tools when your dispatch the action?

Comment: @DacreDenny To answer your question, no.

Comment: Please see answer below - hope this helps you :-)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help - all the best with your project :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working as expected is because you're calling the `login()` action creator, rather than the `login()` method that is returned from `mapDispatchToProps()` (and injected into the `props` of `<ComponentName/>`).

Try revising your code by adding `this.props` before your call to `login()` like so:

```
class <ComponentName> extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

        // Update this line here so that the login() method 
        // injected by connect() is called (ie via this.props)
        this.props.login()
    }

    render() {
        if(this.props.isLogged) 
            return <App/>
        else 
            return <ErrorScreen/>
    }    
}
```